# Firebase 15.0.2 update -android unit test failures

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Unit test fails with below error after upgrading to Firebase 15.0.2. 
This was working fine with firebase version 15.0.0 and started breaking after May 2nd update, moving to 15.0.2 is not fixing the issue.

```html
java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 431
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/firebase/iid/zzal.zze(Landroid/os/Bundle;)Landroid/os/Bundle; @431: pop
  Reason:
    Type 'android/os/Bundle' (current frame, locals[4]) is not assignable to 'android/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap' (stack map, locals[4])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @395
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/firebase/iid/zzal', 'android/os/Bundle', 'java/lang/String', 'com/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource', 'android/os/Bundle', top, top, top, top, top, 'com/google/firebase/iid/zzal', 'android/os/Bundle', 'java/lang/String', 'android/content/Intent', 'com/google/firebase/iid/zzal', 'android/content/Intent', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/InterruptedException' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @431
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/firebase/iid/zzal', 'android/os/Bundle', 'java/lang/String', 'com/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource', 'android/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap', top, top, top, top, top, 'com/google/firebase/iid/zzal', 'android/os/Bundle', 'java/lang/String', 'android/content/Intent', 'com/google/firebase/iid/zzal', 'android/content/Intent', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Exception' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: b800 784d bb00 2e59 b700 6e4e 2ab4 004b
    
    0x00001d0: 2ab4 004b 593a 08c2 2ab4 004b 2cb6 0069
    0x00001e0: 5719 08c3 a700 0b3a 0919 08c3 1909 bf19
    0x00001f0: 07bf                                   
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [291, 322] => handler: 325
    bci [20, 33] => handler: 36
    bci [36, 41] => handler: 36
    bci [405, 417] => handler: 420
  
 at com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.zzaf.create(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.components.zzi.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.components.zzj.get(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.components.zzi.get(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentContainer$$CC.get(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.components.zzg.get(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.components.zzg.zzb(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzc(Unknown Source)
```

Updated Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'



implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this?